# Error trying to install APK programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232615/trying-to-install-apk-with-intent-fails-without-error), my code to install apk after downloading it, is:

```
var downloadIntent: Intent;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    val apkFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "update.apk")
    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(appContext, "${activity?.packageName}.fileprovider", apkFile)
    downloadIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
    downloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    downloadIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
}
appContext.startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

Here's the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
...
 <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

The result is that the package installer silently stops.

Comment: read documentation of `Intent.setFlags` and `Intent.addFlags` ... and check your code again ... hint: think about implication of calling set after add

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Selvin, flags must be set like this:

```
downloadIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
```